# I need some [Output] [Technology], can anyone help?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

Here are some really ambiguous tags:

- [output](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/output) - Used for everything from Command Line output, Logging output, TV/monitor output etc.
- [technology](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/technology) ...Really? ಠ_ಠ

Questions using these tags are already tagged with other, more specific tags. I believe we can safely burn these with no ill effects.

Comment: [tag:output] is now also empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[technology](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/technology) has been removed from questions (and some questions with that tag too...)

Comment: Wait, the entire question was removed? or just the tag :P

Comment: well, sorta both. but anyway

Comment: [tag:output] is now also empty. Please add [meta-tag:status-completed] to this question :)